# Issue with multiple MapHTTPRoutes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am having an issue with utilizing multiple `HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute`

Here is an example of what I have:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AppResourceUserApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{user}/{resource}"
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AppResourceUserMachineNameApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{user}/{resource}/{machinename}"

);
```

What I am currently trying to do is to filter the Get return when the user uses the different options.

For example:

If the user enters `http://API/Items` - they would get a return of all Items.

If the user enters `http://API/Items/John/Resource1/PC001` - They would get a return of all Items that is filtered by `user="John"`, `resource="Resource1"`, `machinename="PC001"`

I have tried using `([FromBody]string user, [FromBody]string resource, [FromBody]string machinename)` as parameters but got the error "Multiple actions were found that match the request" between the DefaultApi and AppResourceUserMachineNameApi Routes.

Is there a way to utilize these mappings to do what I am wanting?

Thanks, Austin

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the routes. More general routes need to be mapped later than more specific routes.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AppResourceUserMachineNameApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{user}/{resource}/{machinename}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AppResourceUserApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{user}/{resource}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

That is because first match wins. With the current order of mappings, the url `http://API/Items/John/Resource1/PC001` would match

```
api/{controller}/{id}
```

where {id} = "John/Resource1/PC001"

but as you experienced it would clash with the other route. But with the suggested order, When it matches an action to the more specific route `api/{controller}/{user}/{resource}/{machinename}` it will use that.

If all else fails you could look into

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Also, that is not how to use the `[FromBody]`. It can only be used once in an action.

Source: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So
>   this will not work:
>
> ```
> // Caution: Will not work!    
> public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
> ```